# Translations of Schwarz and Fricke-Klein

Tags: complex-analysis, translation-request

I am looking for an English, or French translation of two articles. One due to Schwarz and the other due to Fricke and Klein. Both of them are written in German, and unfortunately I do not speak or understand any.

I know that the contents of Schwarz's article may be found in a book by Caratheodory, but it would be interesting to see the insights that Schwarz himself held for one, (in my opinion) of the most beautifull aspects of complex analysis. The articles are the following

Schwarz: Ueber diejenigen Fälle, in welchen die Gaussische hypergeometrische Reihe eine algebraische Function ihres vierten Elementes darstellt. [Schwarz](https://scholar.archive.org/work/3ux3echzrbbjbnosodviaag2se/access/ia_file/crossref-pre-1909-scholarly-works/10.1515%252Fcrll.1870.72.370.zip/10.1515%252Fcrll.1873.75.292.pdf)

Fricke and Klein: Vorlesungen über die Theorie der automorphen Funktionen. [Fricke and Klein](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1903-09-09/S0002-9904-1903-01020-9/)

Thank you!

Comment: For [Fricke and Klein](https://bookstore.ams.org/ctm-3/) the English translation by Art DuPre is available from AMS.